# Podio Webhook - What should the hook syntax be if I want to it to tigger if a specific field in a specific app contains a specific value

Tags: api, syntax, hook, podio

I am trying to detect when a user changes the status of an item in a Podio app. For example:  I have an expenses app in Podio.  I would like to be notified when the status of an item is changed.  The field is a "Category" field type and Let's say the category options are "Pending", "Paid", and "Canceled"  I want to be notified only when the "Paid" category value is active

I can see documentation on Podio's API documentation site for how to create a hook if the value of an item is changed "item.update" but how do you go a bit further to specify that a field is updated to a specific value or condition?

The Podio API hook options referenced above can be found here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks

Answer (score 0):

Podio webhooks doesn't support that granular conditions. You can create webhook for `item.update` which will be fired each time item is modified, you also can create webhook for specific field and it will be fired on any update for that field (so if other fields in item are modified then this webhook won't trigger).

> Additionally, the three hooks item.create, item.update and item.delete
>   can also work on a field level. If you use "app_field" as the ref_type
>   and an app field_id as the ref_id your hook will only be triggered if
>   the changes happen to that particular field.

Also, there is different way of achieving similar result. Have a look on Podio workflows: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204366037-Advanced-workflows . Workflow can be configured to be triggered when specific field is set to specific value which is what you were looking for.